# How do I stop iTunes from re-syncing to iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, voice-memo

I would like to upload voice memos from my iPhone to my computer using iTunes, and then delete them from my iPhone to save space.

However, after deleting my voice memos from my iPhone, it seems that iTunes is set up to automatically re-sync the voice memos back onto the iPhone. How do I stop this from happening?

To summarize: I *do* want my voice memos to go from my iPhone to my PC. But I do not want them to go back to my iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

To solve your problem, just simply go into iTunes with your device connected, and click the little icon of a phone below the play/pause button.

[image: The icon at the bottom right corner]

(The icon at the bottom right corner of picture)

Once in that page, scroll down to the "Options" and uncheck "Automatically sync when this `device` is connected.

[image]

If the "Sync with this `device` over Wi-Fi" is on, you should turn this off as well to prevent accidental syncing.

Hope this helps!